# Springboot 3.1 & Spring Integration 6 - IntegrationComponentScan is not scanning MessagingGateway

Tags: spring-integration

Upgraded springboot from 2.7 to 3.1 and it is dependent spring jars upgraded to version 6. After this upgrade the spring integration flows are failing to process the request.
Throwing error - org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.flows.RaiseFlow$RaiseGateway' available

My MessagingGateway annotation is like below in class "RaiseFlow". And I have tried by adding @Confiration and @IntegrationComponentScan annotation on this class

```
@MessagingGateway(errorChannel = "errorChannel")
    public interface RaiseGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "raiseInputChannel")
        Object raise(Message message);
    }
```

Any input on this is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Would be great to see how you use this `RaiseGateway`. Or even better: share some simple project where we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Sdubba I am facing the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution ?

Comment: Manually importing the interface, by using @Import worked. But in testcases faced "expected single matching bean but found 2" exception.

Comment: @gokul Check if you have multiple IntegrationComponentScan annotations; from SB3.0 only one is processed. If you're importing the gateway manually because its ComponentIntegrationScan is ignored, and your test case only contains that single ComponentIntegrationScan and it does get picked up, that would clash with your manually imported gateway and give you that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have multiple @IntegrationComponentScan annotations. This is no longer supported in Spring Boot 3. You have to load all MessagingGateways with a single @IntegrationComponentScan annotation.